# How to distribute ASP.NET app on lightweight hardware (such as NAS)?

Tags: asp.net, iis, nas

I want to ship a piece of hardware to clients that they plug in to their network via Ethernet or USB. This device contains an ASP.NET web application that they access via a web browser on any PC in their network.

This needs to be a small device that costs less than $500, meaning it can't be a full server with a Win2008 server license. This would be repeated hundreds or thousands of times - once for each new customer.

Are there external hard drives or NAS devices that can run as an IIS/ASP.NET web server?

Thanks,
Roger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you stick with a PC setup, you might be able to use a desktop OS and IIS Express.  It should support everything you want, you might even be able to get this on a cheap netbook.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you could build a small PC based an an embedded motherboard, or even a mini-itx board. But, this is a programming Q&A site and not really the place to ask about building servers.

Comment: Unfortunately, this would require a Win2008 Server license. Maybe I'll ask on serverfault.

Comment: Are you answering the question, or directing the OP to the place where he should be asking his question?  Pick one.

Comment: i was trying to help by suggesting one possible route to take (the embedded/mini-itx board) and also suggesting that a better place to ask this question might be somewhere other than a programming Q&A site. I neglected to mention where might be better though. My bad. But serverfault appears to be known to the OP

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking into keeping it cheap I would highly recommend looking into [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) which is free and runs ASP.Net very well. If you have any Windows-specific things you'd need to possibly change those but hopefully you wouldn't have those on a website.

Comment: Good idea except my ASP.NET app uses Entity Framework, which is currently not supported by Mono.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into converting your app to Mono.Net running on a virtualized environment. The OS and the runtime environment would be open source and would allow you to freely distribute it.

[Mono.Net](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page)

[Virutal Box - VM Enviornment](http://www.virtualbox.org/)

[Ubuntu Linux OS](http://www.ubuntu.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Buy a netbook with windows 7 home premium on it as that bundles IIS7.  If you need any more "capacity", then you should look at bigger hardware anyway.